# Django. Remove object from queryset

Tags: django, django-models

I need to do something like this:

```
quito = queryset.get(lugar="Quito")
queryset.pop(quito)
```

But I get the error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pop'

You can see the details about [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/)

You can try:

```
Yourmodel.objects.exclude(lugar="Quito")
```

to filter the queryset, more details here [Retrieving objects¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects)

Answer (score 13):

How about `queryset.exclude(lugar="Quito")`?

Answer (score 1):

`pop`ping from `set()` or `list()` worked out for me:

```py
quito_set = set(quito)
quito_item = None
while quito_set:
    quito_item = quito_set.pop()
    if quito_item is OK:
        break
```

Comment: The solution provided it's not fully related to the question. The OP asks how to pop an item from a queryset not a set. 

The solution provided by @Windsooon it's appropriated:
Yourmodel.objects.exclude(lugar="Quito")